# Wordpress Contact Form 7 Form with tabs and checkbox

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, checkbox, contact-form-7

[image]I am building a product enquiry form with contact form 7. I would like to get the checkbox value into the form bellow the tabs, I want the user to click on any of the tabs categories and check a desired product and scroll down to fill the form and submit.

I have built the form, however, whenever i click on a different tab and check a product, I can only get the value on a current tab into the form after submission and not the previous checked product on other tabs..

[image]

I need help to get all checked value on the form after submission.

Here is what i have done in contact form. I have also used a tab plugin to display the categories.

```
<div class="tree">
<div class="branch1 noshowin3">
<div class="olumetrixdiv">     
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox dynamicname "CF7_get_custom_field key='my_custom_field'"]
<p class="producttitle">AS608</p>
<ul class="olulist">
     <li> Screening Audiometer</li>
     <li>Hughson-Westlake Auto testing</li>
     <li>Battery operated</li>
     <li>Optional power supply</li>
     <li> PC Integrated option</li>
     <li>pure tone and Warble tone</li>
     <li> Air-condition testing only</li>
     <li>125-8000Hz</li>
</ul>
</label>
</div>

<div class="olumetrixdiv">     
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox AD226 "AD226 - Tick for quote"]
<p class="producttitle">AD226</p>
<ul class="olulist">
     <li>Diagnostic Air & Bone Conduction</li>
     <li>Special tests available as an option</li>
     <li>Pure tone and Warble tone</li>
     <li>125-8000HZ</li>
     <li>PC Integration option</li>
     <li>No Speech Audiometry available</li>
     <li>Hughson-Westlake Auto testing</li>
</ul>
</label>
</div>

<div class="olumetrixdiv">     
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox AD528 "AD528 - Tick for quote"]
<p class="producttitle">AD528</p>
<ul class="olulist">
     <li>Diagnostic Air & Bone free-field</li>
     <li>Speech (CD, MP3, Microphone or Wave)</li>
     <li>Stenger</li>
     <li>Modified Hughson-Westlake</li>
     <li>125 Hz to 8000 Hz</li>
     <li>Special tests available as an option</li>
     <li>Synch License for integration</li>
     <li>Outstanding ergonomics</li>
     <li>Ideal for travelling</li>
</ul>
</label>
</div>

<div class="olumetrixdiv">     
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox AVANT-Stealth-Tick "MedRX: AVANT Stealth-Tick for quote"]
<p class="producttitle">MedRX: AVANT Stealth</p>
<ul class="olulist">
     <li>PC-Based</li>
     <li>Full two channel audiometer</li>
     <li>Diagnostic Air & Bone Conduction</li>
     <li> Full Speech Audio live & recorded</li>
     <li>125-8000 HZ</li>
     <li> Automated Audiometry & High Frequency (20 KHz) option</li>
</ul>
</label>
</div>

<div class="olumetrixdiv">     
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox AVANT-A2D "MedRX:AVANT A2D+ - Tick for quote"]
<p class="producttitle">MedRX: AVANT A2D+</p>
<ul class="olulist">
     <li>PC-Based</li>
     <li>Full two channel audiometer</li>
     <li>Diagnostic Air & Bone Conduction</li>
     <li> Full Speech Audio live + recorded</li>
     <li>125-8000 HZ</li>
     <li> Automated Audiometry</li>
</ul>
</label>
</div>

<div class="olumetrixdiv">     
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox MedRX-Tinnometer "MedRX Tinnometer - Tick for quote"]
<p class="producttitle">MedRX Tinnometer</p>
<ul class="olulist">
     <li>Revolutionary tinnitus assessment</li>
     <li>customized stimulus</li>
     <li>Precise control of level, shape & frequency</li>
     <li>Built-in tinnitus reports</li>
     <li>Save and Recall sessions</li>
     <li> NOAH compatible</li>
</ul>
</label>
</div>

<div class="olumetrixdiv">     
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox AD629 "AD629 - Tick for quote"]
<p class="producttitle">AD629</p>
<ul class="olulist">
     <li>Diagnostic Air & Bone Conduction</li>
     <li>Full Speech Audio live & recorded</li>
     <li>Pure tone and Warble tone</li>
     <li>125-8000Hz</li>
     <li>PC Integration & testing option</li>
     <li>Special tests available as an option</li>
     <li>Hughson-Westlake Auto testing</li>
     <li>High Frequency (20KHz) option</li>
     <li>Option: 2 channel PC control mode</li>
     <li>Option: QuickSIN & TEN test</li>
</ul>
</label>
</div>

<div class="olumetrixdiv">     
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox AC40 "AC40 - Tick for quote"]
<p class="producttitle">AC40</p>
<ul class="olulist">
     <li>Full 2 channel clinical audiometer</li>
     <li>Diagnostic Air & Bone Conduction</li>
     <li>Full Speech Audio live & recorded</li>
     <li>Pure tone and Warble tone</li>
     <li>125-8000Hz</li>
     <li>PC Integration & testing option</li>
     <li>Special tests available as an option</li>
     <li>Hughson-Westlake Auto testing</li>
     <li>High Frequency (20KHz) included</li>
     <li>option: QuickSIN & TEN test</li>
</ul>
</label>
</div>

</div>

<div class="branch2 noshowin3">

<div class="olumetrixdiv">     
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox MT10 "MT10 - Tick for quote"]
        <p class="producttitle">MT10</p>
    <ul class="olulist">
       <li>Screening Tympanometer</li>
       <li>226Hz probe tone</li>
       <li>Handheld unit</li>
       <li>Thermal printer</li>
       <li>available</li>
       <li>optional Ipsillateral reflexes (0.5-4KHz)</li>
    </ul>
      </label>
</div>

<div class="olumetrixdiv">     
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox MedRx-OtoWave-102 "MedRx OtoWave 102- Tick for quote"]
        <p class="producttitle">MedRx OtoWave 102</p>
    <ul class="olulist">
       <li>Screening Tympanometer</li>
       <li>226Hz probe tone</li>
       <li>Ipsllateral reflexes (0.5-4KHz)</li>
    </ul>
      </label>
</div>

<div class="olumetrixdiv">     
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox OtoWave-202-202H "MedRx OtoWave 102- Tick for quote"]
        <p class="producttitle">MedRx OtoWave 102</p>
    <ul class="olulist">
       <li>Screening Tympanometer</li>
       <li>226Hz probe tone</li>
       <li>Ipsllateral reflexes (0.5-4KHz)</li>
    </ul>
      </label>
</div>

<div class="olumetrixdiv">     
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox AA222 "AA222- Tick for quote"]
        <p class="producttitle">AA222</p>
    <ul class="olulist" style="height: 500px;">
       <li>Diagnostic Tympanometer</li>
       <li>226 Hz probe tone</li>
       <li>678, 800, 1000 Hz probe tone optional</li>
       <li>Ipsi & Contra reflexes</li>
       <li>Automatic reflex testing</li>
       <li>Reflex Decay</li>
       <li>Eustachian tube function testing</li>
       <li>Diagnostic Audiometer</li>
       <li>Air & Bone Conduction with masking</li>
       <li>Full Speech Audio live & recorded</li>
       <li>Pure tone and Warbie tone</li>
       <li>125-8000 Hz</li>
       <li>PC Integration Printing</li>
       <li>Special test is available as an option</li>
       <li>Hugh-Westlake Auto testing</li>
       <li>Optional Thermal printer available</li>
       <li>Refer to combined unit solutions</li>
    </ul>
      </label>
</div>

<div class="olumetrixdiv">     
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox Titan "Titan- Tick for quote"]
        <p class="producttitle">Titan</p>
    <ul class="olulist" style="height: 500px;">
       <li>Screening or Diagnostic option</li>
       <li>226 Hz probe tone</li>
       <li>1000Hz probe tone (available on 202H)</li>
       <li>Ipsl Contra reflexes(0.5-4 KHz)</li>
       <li>Automatic reflex testing</li>
       <li>Reflex Decay</li>
       <li>Eustachian tube function testing</li>
       <li>PC Integrated & testing option</li>
       <li>Wideband Tympanometry option</li>
       <li>Handheld unit (battery operated)</li>
       <li>Refer to combined unit solutions</li>
    </ul>
      </label>
</div>

<div class="olumetrixdiv">     
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox AT235 "AT235 - Tick for quote"]
        <p class="producttitle">AT235</p>
    <ul class="olulist" style="height: 500px;">
       <li>Diagnostic Tympanometer</li>
       <li>226Hz probe tone</li>
       <li>1000Hz probe tone optional</li>
       <li>Ipsl & Contra reflexes (0.5-4KHz)</li>
       <li>Automatic reflex testing</li>
       <li>Reflex Decay</li>
       <li>Eustachian tube function testing</li>
       <li>Screening Audiometry (125-8000Hz)</li>
    </ul>
      </label>
</div>


</div>

<div class="branch3">

     <div class="olumetrixdiv">     
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox Titan "Titan - Tick for quote"]
        <p class="producttitle">Titan</p>
    <ul class="olulist" style="height: 500px;">
       <li>DPOAE and/or TEOAE</li>
       <li>Screening or Diagnostic</li>
       <li>DP-Gram</li>
       <li>DP I/O function</li>
       <li>Pressurized DPOAES</li>
       <li>PC Integrated & testing option</li>
       <li>Pass/refer and normative data available</li>
       <li>Handheld unit (battery operate)</li>
       <li>Bluetooth (BT)</li>
       <li>Optional Thermal printer or print via Bluetooth</li>
       <li>Refer to combined unit solutions</li>
    </ul>
      </label>
</div>

<div class="olumetrixdiv">     
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox Sera "Sera - Tick for quote"]
        <p class="producttitle">Sera</p>
    <ul class="olulist" style="height: 500px;">
       <li>Binaural automated ABR screening</li>
       <li>Unique CE-Chirp stimulus reduces test time</li>
       <li>Screening OAE option</li>
       <li>Wireless charging and printing</li>
       <li>Optional Thermal wireless printing via Bluetooth</li>
    </ul>
      </label>
</div>

<div class="olumetrixdiv">     
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox Otoread "Otoread- Tick for quote"]
        <p class="producttitle">Otoread</p>
    <ul class="olulist" style="height: 500px;">
       <li>DPOAE and/or TEOAE</li>
       <li>DP-Gram</li>
       <li>Screening & Diagnostic</li>
       <li>Handheld unit (battery operated)</li>
       <li>Bluetooth</li>
       <li>Optional themal printer or print via bluetooth</li>
    </ul>
      </label>
</div>

<div class="olumetrixdiv">     
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox EP25 "EP25 - Tick for quote"]
        <p class="producttitle">EP25</p>
    <ul class="olulist" style="height: 500px;">
       <li>Diagnostic ABR incl. CE-Chirp stimulus</li>
       <li>MLR, P300</li>
       <li>LLR</li>
       <li>MMN</li>
       <li>EABR</li>
       <li>Cochlear Microphonic</li>
       <li>ECochG</li>
    </ul>
      </label>
</div>

<div class="olumetrixdiv">     
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox EP15 "EP15 - Tick for quote"]
        <p class="producttitle">EP15</p>
    <ul class="olulist" style="height: 500px;">
       <li>Diagnostic ABR</li>
       <li>eABR</li>
       <li>Optional ECochG</li>
       <li>Optional CE Chirp stimulus</li>
    </ul>
      </label>
</div>

<div class="olumetrixdiv">     
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox VEMPs "VEMPs - Tick for quote"]
        <p class="producttitle">VEMPs</p>
    <ul class="olulist" style="height: 500px;">
       <li>cVEMPs</li>
       <li>oVEMPs</li>
    </ul>
      </label>
</div>

<div class="olumetrixdiv">   
<p class="producttitle">DPOAE & TEOEAE</p>   
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox DPOAE-TEOEAE "DPOAE & TEOEAE- Tick for quote"]
      </label>
</div>

<div class="olumetrixdiv">    
<p class="producttitle">AUTOMATED-ABR-ABRIS</p> 
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox AUTOMATED-ABR-ABRIS "ABR-ABRIS- Tick for quote"]
      </label>
</div>

<div class="olumetrixdiv">     
     <p class="producttitle">ASSR </p>
     <label class="olumetrix">[checkbox ASSR "ASSR - Tick for quote"]
      </label>
</div>
</div>


<center class="producttitle">Please provide your details. One of our audiologists will be in touch to conduct a needs analysis and provide you with a customised clinical solution</center>
<div class="olumideform">
    <div>[text* first-name placeholder "First Name*"]</div>
    <div>[text* last-name placeholder "Last Name*"]</div>
    <div>[email* your-email placeholder "Email Address*"]</div>
    <div>[number* contact-number placeholder "Contact Number*"]</div>
    <div>[select* sector placeholder "Select your Sector*" "Government Sector" "Private Sector" "Both Sectors" "Others, Please specify"]</div>
   <div>[select* Occupation placeholder "Select your Occupation*" "Hearing Care Practitioner" "Occupational Health Specialist" "ENT Practitioner" "General Practitioner" "Physiotherapist" "Other, please specify"]</div>
<div>[select* Province placeholder "Select Your Province" "Eastern Cape" "Free State" "Gauteng" "KwaZulu-Natal" "Limpopo" "Mpumalanga" "Northern Cape" "North West" "Western Cape"]</div>
<div>[text* suburb placeholder "Suburb*"]</div>
</div>
<div class="olumideform2">
       <div>[textarea message placeholder "My Message"]</div>
       <div><p>[submit "Send"]</p></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: you could use [CF7 Smart-Grid Layout extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) plugin, it has UI editor to design your form which includes collapsible sections which your users can fill-in before submissions.

Comment: Hello. can you please explain a bit more as to what you're trying to do?  Are there multiple forms, or is this just one form with tabbed input sections?

Comment: It is a single form with multiple tabs section that contain different check-boxes

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to use a custom html, java-script and php to build the form, send submitted data to email and also post submitted data on google sheet, instead of using contact form 7 and google sheet connector.